# minSdk and oom error

Tags: out-of-memory, min

I was almost ready to publish my android app when I suddenly discovered problem. I change minSdk  form 3 to 4, and I receive oom error. Anybody have idea why? (in case when I set minSdk = 3, everything works just perfect)

Error occurs when I call:

`k1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.k1l);`

Of course I use `k1.recylce(); k1 =null;`